# How to show the indentation guide line in Vim for editing haml file

Tags: vim, haml

The following screenshot is comes from `sublime`. The guide line is helpful, since `haml` is an indentation based template engine. Is there anyway to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides), which provides indentation guides.

Answer (score 2):

There's also `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'`:

```
set list
set listchars+=tab:┊\ <-- there's a <Space> after the backslash
```

but it works only with `<Tab>`s which may or may not suit your needs.